# Запрос join using с промежуточной таблицей

Tags: sql, join, using

Не могу разобраться с заданием, помогите, пожалуйста
• Вывести таблицу из двух колонок (база данных HR). В первой колонке имя и фамилия работника (first_name и last_name), разделенных одним пробелом. Во второй колонке адрес департамента, к котором работает сотрудник Адрес департамента задать в виде city||’’||street_address. Оба поля содержатся в таблице location. (Поскольку у таблиц employеes и locations нет общих полей использовать таблицу departments как промежуточную). При составлении запроса использовать вид соединения …JOIN… USING

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как использовать "промежуточную таблицу"

таблица employees: first_name, last_name, department_id

locations: city, street_address, location_id

departments: location_id, department_id

```
SELECT first_name||' '|| last_name, city||''||street_address 
FROM employees JOIN locations USING(department_id, location_id)
```

Понимаю, что в ходе этого запроса ошибка в том, что поля department_id нет в таблице location, а location_id нет в employees
Как добавить сюда промежуточную таблицу departments, используя join using?

Comment: В задачи с SQL принято добавлять код для создания всех необходимых таблиц с нужными типами полей, а также несколько инсертов с тестовыми данными.

Comment: К таблице employees нужно сначала присоединить таблицу departments по полю department_id, а затем к таблице departments присоединить таблицу locations через поле location_id